# U.S. Amending Tax - Should a 1040x be made if I forgot to include 1099-r but there is no difference in taxable income?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, roth-ira, form-1099, amended-tax-return

I was notified last year when I went to the tax office that I didn't include a 1099-r early distribution.

This is the distribution in question: [image]

I am confused because the TurboTax UI shows my distribution, but when I looked at the `1040` PDF output, box `15a` and `b` are blank—so this makes me think that *somehow* TurboTax filed without that information somehow?

Now, when I go back into TurboTax to add that distribution, it says it already exists. So when I print a `1040x`, it shows my original `1040` as containing the $4,000 in box `15`. When I try removing and re-adding the distribution, TurboTax somehow still remembers and preserves the $4,000 in box `15`.

However, when I added the `1099-r`, it didn't change my taxable income or taxes owed. Should I bother with the `1040x` amendment? I keep seeing a lot of responses online about `1099` that say, "Yes you should technically, but I wouldn't do it…"

But in my case, I am wasn't rolling over or anything, I was withdrawing. So that makes me think the IRS will catch it.

I've had my IRA for 5+ years and my contributions exceed my withdrawal FWIW, so I think that is why I wasn't getting taxed for the distribution?

Advice?